# binding data in asp checkbox list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I bind some data in a dropdownlist control using below code:

```
$.each(result, function (key, value) {
      $("#" + sPropertyID).append($("<option></option>").val($(this).attr('value')).html($(this).attr('value1')));
});
```

likewise how can I bind data in an ASP checkboxlist, here 'sPropertyID' is the id of the dropdownlist

Comment: you want to create multiple checkbox or bind to single checkbox

Comment: bind to single checkboxlist

Comment: What is a "checkboxlist"?

Answer (score 0):

The below URL explains how to bind data in checkboxlist via Ajax and Jquery.

You can modify it for dropdownlist as well

http://brijbhushan.net/2013/08/26/bind-a-checkbox-list-from-database-using-jquery-ajax/